# How to effectively redraw multiple matplotlib plots with blit

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm using matplotlib with pyqt5 to draw data into 3 axes, and than user can make selection in one plot that will be shown in other two plots too. Since I'm working with big data (up to 10 millions of points), drawing selection could be slow, especially when I need to draw to scatterplot.

I am trying to use matplotlib blit function, but have some issues with result. Here is minimum simple example.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import numpy as np
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        self.static_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        layout.addWidget(self.static_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(self.static_canvas, self))
        axes = self.static_canvas.figure.subplots(2, 1)
        self.ax1 = axes[0]
        self.ax2 = axes[1]
        self.ax1.cla()
        self.ax2.cla()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me!')
        button.clicked.connect(self.update_canvas_blit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        # Fixing random state for reproducibility
        np.random.seed(19680801)

        # Create random data
        N = 50000
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        y = np.random.rand(N)

        self.ax1.scatter(x, y)
        self.points = self.ax1.scatter([],[], s=5, color='red')

        x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100000)
        self.ax2.plot(x, np.sin(x))
        self.lines, = self.ax2.plot([],[], color='red')
        self.static_canvas.draw()

        self.background1 = self.static_canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax1.bbox)
        self.background2 = self.static_canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax2.bbox)

    def update_canvas_blit(self):
        N = 50
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        y = np.random.rand(N)

        self.static_canvas.restore_region(self.background1)
        self.points.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])
        self.ax1.draw_artist(self.points)
        self.ax1.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax1.bbox)

        self.static_canvas.restore_region(self.background2)
        x = np.linspace(0, np.random.randint(500,1000), 1000)
        self.lines.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
        self.ax2.draw_artist(self.lines)
        self.ax2.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax2.bbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

When clicking button, expected output should be still same background with random points/lines redrawing. In a way it is happening but there are some strange artifacts that looks like somehow axes are drawn to each other. But when I try to save it to .png, it will restore to good state.

[image: blit_update]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the snapshot of the background is taken at a moment in time where the figure has not yet been shown on screen. At that point the figure is 10 by 10 inches large. Later, it is shown inside the QMainWindow and resized to fit into the widget.
Only once that has happened, it makes sense to take the background snapshot.

One option is to use a timer of 1 second and only then copy the background. This would look as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)

        self.static_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(10, 10)))
        layout.addWidget(self.static_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(NavigationToolbar(self.static_canvas, self))
        axes = self.static_canvas.figure.subplots(2, 1)
        self.ax1 = axes[0]
        self.ax2 = axes[1]
        self.ax1.cla()
        self.ax2.cla()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me!')
        button.clicked.connect(self.update_canvas_blit)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        # Fixing random state for reproducibility
        np.random.seed(19680801)

        # Create random data
        N = 50000
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        y = np.random.rand(N)

        self.ax1.scatter(x, y)
        self.points = self.ax1.scatter([],[], s=5, color='red')

        x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100000)
        self.ax2.plot(x, np.sin(x))
        self.lines, = self.ax2.plot([],[], color='red')
        self.static_canvas.draw()

        self._later()


    def _later(self, evt=None):
        self.timer = self.static_canvas.new_timer(interval=1000)
        self.timer.single_shot = True
        self.timer.add_callback(self.update_background)
        self.timer.start()


    def update_background(self, evt=None):
        self.background1 = self.static_canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax1.bbox)
        self.background2 = self.static_canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax2.bbox)

    def update_canvas_blit(self):
        N = 50
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        y = np.random.rand(N)

        self.static_canvas.restore_region(self.background1)
        self.points.set_offsets(np.c_[x,y])
        self.ax1.draw_artist(self.points)
        self.ax1.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax1.bbox)

        self.static_canvas.restore_region(self.background2)
        x = np.linspace(0, np.random.randint(500,1000), 1000)
        self.lines.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
        self.ax2.draw_artist(self.lines)
        self.ax2.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax2.bbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Since I don't use `figsize` argument in my application when creating figure (I used it here just as an example), I can remove it from my example and it also works.